What is the SFTP num_requests parameter?
I've found this in the man page of sftp:

-R num_requests
Specify how many requests may be outstanding at any one time.  Increasing this may
slightly improve file transfer speed but will increase memory usage.  The
default is 64 outstanding requests.

What are outstanding requests? What exactly is this parameter used for?

See also Speed up SFTP uploads on high latency network?

"Outstanding" here is OED meaning number two:

not yet paid, resolved, or dealt with.

In the context of sftp, it refers to the number of file transfer operations that the client sends to the server simultaneously without a response. That is, this is how many requests can be in flight simultaneously, which directly impacts how data is pipelined during transfer.
Increasing this value can improve transfer speeds in high-latency networks, because the client does not need to wait for a response to one request before sending the next. Instead, it keeps a steady stream of requests flowing to maximise throughput. However, a higher value for -R also increases memory usage, as more requests and responses must be buffered. On a low-latency network, the default of 64 is usually sufficient, as the overhead of waiting for individual responses is minimal.
It is likely that in the majority of cases you do not need to touch this configuration value. That said, you may need to tune this parameter if:

You are experiencing slow file transfer speeds on high-latency networks. In that case, increasing the number of outstanding requests may allow better utilisation of available bandwidth by reducing the time spent waiting for individual responses.
Your network has high throughput but transfers are not saturating the connection. Although in that case this may not help, since it's possible you're reaching a limitation at the server end.
You are running on a system with limited memory resources. Decreasing the number of outstanding requests can reduce memory usage if higher values are consuming too much in the way of file caches or other resources.


great, thank you for these details :)
